# Installing on a Vaio S

Tags: installation, 11.04, graphics, vaio

I have a new Vaio S 15" with Windows 8 pre-installed and UEFI. It had both Intel on-board graphics and nVidia discrete graphics. Installing Ubuntu has turned into a nightmare.

1. Installing from Live USB with default settings results in a black screen and freeze after the splash screen.
2. Replacing `quick splash` with `nomodeset` in GRUB (this seems fairly common) gets further - but the install then hangs with `fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs VESA VGA - removing generic driver` as the last message.
3. I can 'Try without installing' and get to the command line with `i915.modeset=0`, but I am not sure where - if anywhere - I can go after that. This does not work for the install.

I have run out of bug reports that match mine and not at all sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 64-bit version instead of the 32-bit version. The 64-bit version handles UEFI better than the 32-bit one.